# Getting AJAX Loaded content indexed by Google

Tags: ajax

Ok, first question on stackoverflow!

I'm in a bit of a dilemma, I've recently created an ecommerce site and set it up to load everything very nicely with AJAX for speed, UX & UI. However it appears that the search engines (Google) is not indexing the content. Doing a bit of research the popular answer/fix that comes back is to implement Googles guide here: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

To cut a long story short I don't really want to be using 'hash bangs' across the site, the URL's I currently use are simple and clean and littering them with #! just doesn't look nice! Before I start to go down this route does is there any alternatives? I currently use history.pushState on the category pages but I need something primarily for the product detail page tat doesn't involve changing the URL.

This is the current setup for loading the product details:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    LoadContent();
});

function LoadContent() {
     Services.Content.GetProduct(productid, OnSuccess, OnFailure);
}
function OnSuccess(result) {
     $('#ContentLoading').css("display", "none");
     $('#Content').hide();
     $('#Content').html(result);
     $('#Content').delay(200).fadeIn();
}
```

Comment: If you're loading everything with ajax, surely you only have one page, and therefore one url?

Comment: Hi Eric, not everything is loaded on one page, categories and products are kept separate, they have their own pages and own URL's. The content for each is then loaded using the JavaScript above.

Comment: So if someone visits your site with javascript disabled, they see nothing? Can't the server just load the content directly into the HTML?